# different type of obj for response_add() and response_delete()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I modified my response_add and response_delete action in my admin app.

My codes is in below.

```
def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
    print(obj, type(obj))
    return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)


def response_delete(self, request, obj):
    print(obj, type(obj))
    return super().response_add(request, obj)
```

I don't know why in my response_add the type of variable *obj* is object but in reponse_delete is a string which I need is an object also.

And when I try to query in the model using the variable *obj* inside the response_delete action it cannot query the data because it is already deleted.

Comment: Please check `response_delete`, Is it `return super().response_add(request, obj)` ? or `super().response_delete(request, obj)`

Comment: @all3g even I use either of the two I still get a string type of my variable obj in my def response_delete method. I need it to be an object. Thanks for the comment anyway.

Comment: I'm not able to test it right now (or find documentation) but I'm assuming that obj in the first instance is the newly added object. whilst delete is giving a string representation of the now defunct object.

Comment: @Sayse that makes sense. Is there a way to make it an object? Actually what I only needed is the parent model of the obj. Since it was a string I tried to query it in the model but It returns an error because the data was already deleted. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I've found so far that calls `response_delete` is the [`DeleteView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1720)

Which has a comment a few lines above it stating that the object has been deleted.

```
if request.POST and not protected:  # The user has confirmed the deletion.
    if perms_needed:
        raise PermissionDenied
    obj_display = force_text(obj)
    attr = str(to_field) if to_field else opts.pk.attname
    obj_id = obj.serializable_value(attr)
    self.log_deletion(request, obj, obj_display)
    self.delete_model(request, obj)

    return self.response_delete(request, obj_display, obj_id)
```

Therefore there is nothing left to query about it, it has no data left attached to it.

> why in my response_add the type of variable obj is object but in reponse_delete is a string which I need is an object also.

- `response_add` is returning the newly created object
- `response_delete` is returning a string representation of the defunct object

So what can you do?

Most likely you need a [`pre_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_delete) signal to do so pre-processing but its hard to say.

Comment: thanks for this great explanation. Yup. I also think that pre_delete is my only way to get the corresponding object I need. Appreciated.